# Print either an integer or a float with n decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, int, precision

In Python, how can one print a number that might be an integer or real type, when the latter case would require me to limit my printout to a certain amount of digits?

Long story short, say we have the following example:

```
print("{0:.3f}".format(num)) # I cannot do print("{}".format(num))
                             # because I don't want all the decimals
```

Is there a "Pythy" way to ensure e.g. in case `num == 1` that I print `1` instead of `1.000` (I mean other than cluttering my code with `if` statements)

Comment: Part of the problem is that `int` treats `.3` the same way as `float` does, instead of say, ignoring it completely.

Comment: My guess would be no, you would need to at least do a ternary operator somewhere along the way, and I am pretty sure you count that as an `if`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Python 3*, you can just use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) because in addition to rounding `float`s, when applied to an integer it will always return an `int`:

```
>>> num = 1.2345
>>> round(num,3)
1.234
>>> num = 1
>>> round(num,3)
1
```

This behavior is documented in `help(float.__round__)`:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

__round__(...)
    Return the Integral closest to x, rounding half toward even.
    When an argument is passed, work like built-in round(x, ndigits).
```

And `help(int.__round__)`:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

__round__(...)
    Rounding an Integral returns itself.
    Rounding with an ndigits argument also returns an integer.
```

* With Python 2, `round()` always `return`s a `float`.

Comment: I never knew `round` was so versatile. It would never have occurred to me to use it on an `int`.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but this won't give the same output as the format spec in the question with shorter float values (i.e. `1.2` vs `1.200`).

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I agree it's not quite clear what the desired behavior is there, I up-voted your solution

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, yes in fact when ndigits is a negative integer, `round()` on integers can be quite useful, for example `round(210,-2)` `return`s `200`

Answer (score 6):

If you need to maintain a fixed-width for float values, you could use the [printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), like this:

```
>>> num = 1
>>> print('%0.*f' % (isinstance(num, float) * 3, num))
1
>>> num = 1.2345
>>> print('%0.*f' % (isinstance(num, float) * 3, num))
1.234
>>> num = 1.2
>>> print('%0.*f' % (isinstance(num, float) * 3, num))
1.200
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a fix number of floating point, you could just use a replace to remove the extra `0`. For instance this would do the trick:

```
print("{:.3f}".format(1).replace(".000", ""))
```

Comment: Works great unless the requirement is to display `1.0` as `1.000`.

Answer (score 0):

For fix number of decimal point:

```
>>> num = 0.2
>>> print('%.04*f' % num)
0.2000

>>> num = 3.102
>>> print('%.02*f' % num)
3.10
```